# C# Semaphores not working as expected, cannot figure out why

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am building an ASP.NET (.NET Framework) application in C# I am making API calls to a backend service called "LinuxDocker" and I am trying to limit the number of 12 concurrent calls to it from the ASP.NET application.  Here is the code I wrote:

```
private static Semaphore LinuxDockerSemaphore = new Semaphore(12, 12);

public static SemaphoreWaiter WaitForLinuxDocker(int timeoutMS = -1)
{
      return new SemaphoreWaiter(LinuxDockerSemaphore, timeoutMS);
}

public class SemaphoreWaiter : IDisposable
{
    Semaphore Slim;

    public SemaphoreWaiter(Semaphore slim, int timeoutMS = -1)
    {
        Slim = slim;
        Slim.WaitOne(timeoutMS);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Slim.Release();
    }
}
```

Then when I call my backend service, I do so like this:

```
using (ConcurrencyManager.WaitForLinuxDocker())
{
      // Call backend service here
}
```

So it seems like this should limit to 12 concurrent calls, however when I test it from an integration test with 100 simultaneous calls, it basically only allows 1 request at a time to go through, not 12 calls at a time to go through.

The service is running on IIS on Windows Server 2016 and .NET Framework 4.7.

I have read this code many times and can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are blocking the current thread by calling `WaitOne`. You could potentially be running into a threadpool starvation scenario where there are simply just not enough threads to respond to the calls due to blocking. This then could _look_ like the semaphore isn't working correctly. I would change to `SemaphoreSlim` and use `WaitAsync`

Comment: @JohanP thanks for the feedback.  FWIW I actually tried SemaphoreSlim first and when it wasn't working then I tried Semaphore.  Both created the exact same result (not working as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly your backend is being served up by multiple `w3wp.exe` worker processes. Because your semaphore is created without a name it is a "local" semaphore (local to each process) as opposed to a "global" semaphore (system-wide):

> Semaphores are of two types: local semaphores and named system semaphores. If you create a Semaphore object using a constructor that accepts a name, it is associated with an operating-system semaphore of that name. Named system semaphores are visible throughout the operating system, and can be used to synchronize the activities of processes. You can create multiple Semaphore objects that represent the same named system semaphore, and you can use the OpenExisting method to open an existing named system semaphore.
>
> A local semaphore exists only within your process. It can be used by any thread in your process that has a reference to the local Semaphore object. Each Semaphore object is a separate local semaphore.

REF: [Semaphore Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore)

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, will try this.  Wouldn't this actually increase the parallelism though, not decrease it to 1?  Should I initialize each Semaphore to 0 and then release it?